# Steps to take Native Android build from Sencha Touch 2.3.2

Tags: android, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd, sencha-touch-2.3

I am struggling for the past 5 days to get a native build from Sencha Touch application. Surfed a lot but I cannot find the same procedure given by many .Tried few but failed. Can any one help me to get a Android build. Am a native Android developer.

Comment: Check out the answer on related question: [Build a simple app using Sencha, not working on Android 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488922/build-a-simple-app-using-sencha-not-working-on-android-4?rq=1)

Comment: I followed the steps. I got stuck again and I surfed related to that. Its said that I should have compass installed to complete the process without fail. Do I need to install compass ?

Comment: I installed compass. Then i tried the steps given in the link provided by you. But I ended with 'STBuild is no longer supported in
 Cmd 5. Please use the cordova or phonegap packager for device packaging'

Comment: Sencha stbuild command will not work on Linux. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?275924-Sencha-Cmd-v4.0.1.45-stbuild-Error-after-update

Comment: Cordova is quite easy to use to wrap your javascript project into an Android app, I've used it a few times before. The intro tut is very easy to follow, so check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/cordova

After doing this, execute these commands:

cd /path/to/app/cordova;
  cordova build android --release;
  cd platforms/android/ant-build

Then jarsign and zipalign which I'm sure are familiar as a native android dev.